# Adding a library file to an already existing debian package file .deb

Tags: packaging, deb

I have a debian package file (.deb) that's missing a key library. I don't know specifics of creating a debian package. Is it possible to just add this one library file into the debian package?

Comment: Which package it is? which library it misses

Comment: It's a private debian package

Comment: Please be more specific in what you want to do exactly. How was the Deb package built originally? Can you give us a rough outline of it and where you want to add which files? Can the library dependency satisfied by a library from a different package?

Comment: Unless the library can be added by creating another package, the private .deb needs to be rebuilt from the source package with the missing library added into the package and set up correctly to create the links, etc. in the system.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I mentioned I don't know specifics of creating deb packages. So I don't know how it was built originally. Yes, the library that's required I already have with me and simply copying that into my system works. It's just not a part of the .deb file.

Comment: @simplename: I appreciate your effort, but you're only answering the first of my questions. What is the directory structure inside of the Deb packages (e. g. from `dpkg-deb -c <DEB>`) and where in that structure do you want to place which (shared?) library files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If copying that particular library file in your installed system works, it should work too if you insert the library in your private deb package.

A debian package file is nothing but an archive of some files, with metadata about those files and some (optional) scripts that are executed when the files are copied over the system .i.e `/`.

Lets say, your system `/usr/lib` is this without the missing library say, `necessary-lib.so`

```
├── usr
│   ├── lib 
│   │   ├── lib1.so
│   │   ├── lib2.so
│   │   ├── <missing lib necessary-lib.so> 
│   │   ├── lib3.so
```

and copying the library file in `/usr/lib/` worked.

Then you can extract the deb file and put the library file in `usr/lib` directory of the extracted files and repackage it.

**How do you inject the library**

First make a folder to extract the deb file

```
mkdir extracted
```

Then extract your deb file. I'm assuming its name is `mypackage.deb`.

```
dpkg-deb -R mypackage.deb extracted/
```

This will extract the package in `extracted` folder. There will be a folder named `DEBIAN` with some other folders like those ones in `/`. You should find a `usr` folder there and in that a `lib` folder. You'd copy your library file there.

The theory is, you'll copy the library file in the same location of the extracted folder assuming it as the root of your system. So, you'll copy it in `extracted/usr/lib`

```
cp necessary-lib.so extracted/usr/lib
```

Now, re-build the deb package using this command.

```
dpkg-deb -b extracted
```

It will create a new `extracted.deb` file. It's your new deb file. You should be able to install it on multiple systems now without having to copy the library file each time after installation.

Comment: Yes, copying that library file to the system works. This is exactly what I was looking for!